# Given more than $3$ dimensions, would I be able to slice my apple more than one time and still being able to place it in a table in a particular way?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

My english is okay, but not good enough to describe this, so I made a picture.

This is what happens in our real life (boring) $3$D world,

[image]

Note that if we slice the apple one more time (unless you slice again, parallel to the earlier cut), there's no way of putting your apple in the table having the face(s) of the region that's been cut touching the table, and the rest (the curvy parts) not touching it.

Is it possible to make more cuts like the one showed while still being able to achieve the condition above in more than $3$ dimensions?

PS: Please ask for clarification if needed, this is kind of difficult to explain (especially not using my native language).

Comment: Clarification: do you mean a slice of a higher-dimensional apple which can be placed on a 3-dimensional table (really a plane) such that the sliced side is the only side facing the 3-dimensional table (plane)? Or do you mean an n-dimensional apple on an n-dimensional table?

Comment: Also: you can cut the apple, parallel, in 3-dimensions such that there is an exposed cut side - just make the parallel cut on the opposite side of the apple. But I think what you meant was a cut that was parallel and removed the previous cut. That being said, any two cuts such that the second cut (parallel or not) removes the plane generated by the first cut would be two cuts that result in 1 plane.

Comment: @SubSevn I meant $n$ dimensional sphere on $n$ dimensional table, the higher dimensional apple on 3d table seems a cool idea though. I'm sorry but I didn't understand your second comment.

Comment: Oh, I just added an answer for 3d table. Please define what an $n$ dimensional table is supposed to mean.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD What I meant was that if I cut an apple on one side, and then I make non-parallel cut on the same side such that the previous cut I was "cut off", then I have made two non-parallel cuts and the apple can still sit on the table with the properties you have described. Consider cutting it in half, then cutting one of the halves such that the two cuts do not intersect. You'd end up with one plane, but you made two cuts.

Comment: @SubSevn Isn't this effectively a single cut, since the remaining shape maintains no information about the first cut, or in general the number of cuts that lead to this configuration?

Comment: @Kagaratsch I think it is effectively a single cut, and I agree that the shape has lost that information, but I don't think without knowing the original shape you can make cuts that don't lose information at all.

Comment: @SubSevn I agree, cuts generally remove some information. However, in order to call something "second cut" we imply that knowledge of a "first cut" is available to us, otherwise the name would be unfounded. Therefore, the whole discussion only makes sense for $n$th cuts which preserve some information about the $n-1$ previous cuts in the resulting shape.

Comment: @Kagaratsch I agree, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Approximate an apple in i.e. $D=4$ as a unit sphere of radius $R$, where the outer shell is defined by the coordinates

$$\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i^2=R^2$$

If we are talking about a table (as used by humans) then we are basically considering a $D=2$ surface where objects can be placed upon.

After performing the first cut, orient your coordinate system such that the cut surface coincides with table surface - the sphere (apple) is put on the table with the cut surface downwards.

By the remaining $SO(3)$ rotational symmetry of the cut sphere (rotation axis through the original center of the sphere, and normal to and through the center of the surface of the cut), we can project the shape onto a $D=3$ cut sphere without losing information. Furthermore, the $D=3$ cut sphere still has an $SO(2)$ symmetry (same rotational axis), so we can proceed to project it onto a cut $D=2$ sphere (cut off circle) without losing information.

As we try to apply the second cut, we can always orient our double projections above such that the second cut appears as a line in the cut circle. Therefore, whether we start in $D=3$ or $D=4$ or general $D\in\mathbb{N},D>2$ to apply the initial cut, by symmetry the problem reduces to just a cut circle and the result is the same:

You cannot cut a $D$ dimensional sphere twice and put it on a table such that no cut surface can be seen, unless your second cut removes all information about the first cut from the remaining shape.